# Map Texture to Plane without distortion

Tags: three.js

In Three.js, how can I change the way in which a texture gets mapped onto a plane?

Let's assume we have a 1x1 plane and a 16:9 image. How can I control the way in which that image gets mapped onto the plane?

By default, the image gets "squished". I would like it to maintain its aspect ratio and have any overlap get "cut off". Is there a way to configure the material or texture to do this, or would I use a shader? If so, what would it need to look like?

```js
const planeMesh = new THREE.Mesh(
    new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(1, 1),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        map: texture,
    })
);
```

PS: In future, I would also like to be able to zoom into and out of the image on mouse hover without affecting the size of the plane, so would think a shader might be better?

Answer (score 4):

A `Texture` already has several properties built-in that can do what you're looking for.

```js
const texture = textureLoader.load("whatever.png");

const planeMesh = new THREE.Mesh(
    new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(1, 1),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        map: texture,
    })
);

// Sets the pivot point to the center of the texture
texture.center.set(0.5, 0.5);

// Make the texture repeat 0.5625 times in the x-axis to match 16:9 ratio
let ratio = 9 / 16;
texture.repeat.set(ratio, 1);

// Scale texture up to "zoom" into it
let zoom = 0.5;
texture.repeat.set(ratio * zoom, 1 * zoom);
```

You can read more about the `.repeat` `.center` and even `.rotation` properties [in the Texture docs](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/textures/Texture.repeat). Just keep in mind that repeating a texture is a bit counter-intuitive because you're doing the inverse of scaling a texture. So to scale a texture by 2, you have to tell it to repeat 1/2 times.

Comment: Thanks, that's a great start! Some questions: What if the plane is not 1:1? What if the image is not 16:9? Can you make your answer more generic, please?

Comment: @Ben If the image is not 16:9, then you can modify the numbers in the division for `ratio`. If the plane is not 1:1, you can arrive at the solution with some basic algebra. I'm confident you can take it from here! :)